# Let's fix all the broken images

Tags: discussion, images

One of the steps on Stack Exchange's [road to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/295684) is the replacing of embedded `http://` images with secure ones. This has been done automatically for a lot of images, but there are some that can't be automatically fixed. These were rewritten in the HTML (but not the Markdown source) to be text links instead of image embeds. It would be good to go through the affected posts and make images display correctly, or remove the link debris if they can't be restored.

Since there [seems to be a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only#comment949230_291947) with the CrowdCrafting task's data, I used [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/revision/639606/799214/posts-with-more-image-markdown-than-html-images) (slightly adjusted from [this version](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/revision/639580/799211/posts-with-more-image-markdown-than-html-images) by Jefromi) to find a few hundred posts that may require our attention.

To continually track our progress, we have **[a Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGmL-Ie0mNyCG5dpz7AAhn3sRaoNWkBJ0OvSoEacezs/edit?usp=sharing)**. (Even though all the links have `/q/`, answers are included too.) The Status column is editable by anyone, so please note your work there as you go along.

As usual when doing big batches of edits, try to avoid flooding the front page, and please try to fix all obvious problems before submitting an edit.

Comment: Could this not be done at the database level? BTW, I'm playing devil's advocate here.

Comment: @Burgi Unfortunately, the remaining images are not accessible over HTTPS. Apparently, Stack Exchange can't automatically upload HTTP images to an HTTPS source for licensing reasons. For more discussion of the image transition, see [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291948/295684) and its comments. (I do agree that it would be great if this could be done automatically for us!)

Comment: I've just discovered that not all the `http://` in that list directly relate to images. Perhaps a tweak to the query is needed to see if the URL ends in `jpg`, `png` or `gif`?

Comment: @Burgi Ah, if `![` appears in the post, the query assumes it's an image, even if it's actually escaped. My SQL skills are not strong enough to deal with that, but I would be happy to link any improved query!

Comment: Feels like a good time to do a free for all tag cleanup. Let me consult the other mods and see if there's any violent objections and I'll post a meta post for that.

Comment: what is the guidance for 404s? Nuke or leave in place?

Comment: If you can find an appropriate/logical alternative, go ahead and include it. If you can edit out the image link and the post makes sense, go ahead. If its trivial to generate a new image, go ahead. Otherwise, I guess we need to go by a case by case basis

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Is this something a low rep user can assist with? Or, would that just make more work by loading the review queue with my edits?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver An edit approval is faster, then doing the edit, feel free to help

Comment: Yes please! Do link back here in the edit reasons so people know what's happening and do other appropriate fixes as needed

Comment: Might want to add a filter to the spreadsheet. I tried to do so  but visible only to me

Comment: Suggest working from the spreadsheet.  The query has a lot of false positives, including posts that have been fixed.  People will spend a lot of time revisiting posts that have already been reviewed.  Updating the status column on the spreadsheet will save people a lot of time.

Comment: @fixer1234 Good idea; I've edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Sathya Done, I think; there should now be an "unexamined posts" option under the filter icon. (Sorry, I'm not super familiar with Google apps.)

Comment: thanks for the filter @BenN might I suggest having status next to URL? Will help in click/update status

Comment: @Sathya Good idea, done. The protection should still be working as before (with the Status column in its new place).

Comment: I like the new position of the Status column. Much more convenient. I've been placing "User screenshot no longer available" there for cases where the dead image link was a screenshot of something unique to the user that can't be recreated. Hopefully to let others know that there's no point in trying to do anything to them. "Image no longer available," OTOH _might_ be salvaged by creating a new image, or finding a reasonable substitute for it.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Yes, classifying those things separately is a good idea. Once we finish looking at all the posts, we can go back and decide what to do with the ones that couldn't be repaired.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I'm a little confused as to what exactly the aim is here, and the question doesn't make it clea. Is it a simple case of changing the `http` in SE-hosted image links to `https` and then updating that it's been fixed in the spreadsheet? If so, how would I get around the limitation that prevents me from making 1-letter edits?

Comment: @Hashim The SE-hosted image links have all been automatically fixed for us. What's left are those that aren't on SE and aren't accessible over HTTPS - we can reupload the existing HTTP-only ones to Imgur. There are also plenty that are broken over both protocols; these need to be tracked down if possible, or replaced.

Comment: Got it, thanks. What about the character limitation?

Comment: @Hashim I think reuploading the images to Imgur should change the URL enough. Either way, please try to also fix all clear problems with the post, e.g. if there are misspellings or formatting issues, it'd be good to correct those in the same edit. If there's nothing else to fix and the URL change isn't substantial enough, you can leave it for a >2K user to handle.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of images that are already hosted on Imgur, and would presumably just need the "s" adding to "http", and also don't need any additional edits. In any case, I'll just re-upload, I'm sure no harm can come from having a few additional images hosted on Imgur. One more thing again - when edits have been made, do I remove the entry from the spreadsheet or simply add a note that it's been updated? I want to clarify as much as possible so I'm not leaving much work for anyone else.

Comment: @Hashim I think the HTTP → HTTPS URL changes for Imgur are automatically handled, so there shouldn't be any such instances in the spreadsheet. Once you fix a post, please update the Status column to say "Fixed"; there are a few other statuses that people have been using for other cases.

Comment: That makes sense. Will do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BenN Actually, many of the imgur-hosted image links are _not_ corrected in the text. I think they are handled on the fly when serving the page, however. They do still show in the spreadsheet. I have been able to fix them by doing, as you suggested, general cleanup and formatting of the posts.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Ah, that's interesting. Thanks for the note!

Comment: IIRC the meta post about the switch said that was how they would handle the imgur links during the switch. They were waiting for the imgur switch to https to be complete before they went further with the rollout.

Answer (score 8):

Summing up the comments

Here's what we essentially need.

High reputation users should probably keep an eye on the edit queue -and *improve and accept* rather than *reject* edits related to this fix up. If you're a lower rep user, feel free to edit, and link back here (and if you see anything that needs to be fixed up along with images, please do so). This feels like a great opportunity to get people to fix things.

If an image can't be found, and a reasonable best effort with the waybackmachine doesn't help, feel free to replace the image with a suitable replacement if it's 'obvious', or remove it if the post can manage without it. If neither helps, leave it alone first (for now!) and we can work out what to do later.

I'd add its an *excellent* chance for people to work towards copy editor and steward badges.

I'm going to see if the other mods, and the community are on board with having an (extended?) period for cleanups like the tag cleanup weekend we had a little back. We should probably take the chance to handle the tag cleanup backlogs as well. In theory, don't flood the front page for now, but I would be slightly more inclined to be sympathetic if it happens than I would normally be.

Non https stack.imgur links should be [autofixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only) - but there's probably no hard in swapping the protocol there

Comment: Haven't been here long enough to know what "flood the front page" means, nor how to _not_ do it. At a guess, an edited post become "current" again, and moves to the front of the list? If so, then it seems to make sense to work from oldest-to-newest in the fix. That way, as the newer posts get edited and move up, they naturally move the older ones that moved up because of the edit back down to something that more resembles their prior position. _I think?_

Comment: Yeah, and a lot of people only use the main page, so bumping kinda disrupts the way we find questions to answer. Typically the advice is not to do too many edits at once - though we work around that by declaring open season on necessary edits periodically.

Comment: I'm slow enough that my work won't disrupt very much at all :) Too bad there isn't a tool for mods to override that behavior. Not that the developers don't have enough to do already.

Comment: eh. We can solve this as a social rather than a technical problem. That's why we have mods after all, handling exceptions.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is better to ask in chat, only I don't know how/where, so... Reviewing one of the [posts](https://superuser.com/questions/20340/connecting-to-canon-pixma-ip4000r-over-the-network/20342#20342) to edit I found five dead links in the text. Removing the links won't change the text, or answer, at all. The static versions of the links are in Wayback, but they server no purpose because they don't link further into material that the post refers to. Do I remove the dead links, and keep the text, while fixing the image link?

Comment: I'd go for removing the links if non essential, or sticking a way back machine link if it helps. For now, I suppose root access is the place to go. I practically just started working on getting this started a few hours ago. - so I'm still dekinking all the kinks.