# Cleanup Week? When and How?

Tags: discussion

We have [nearly a thousand posts](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12189/lets-fix-all-the-broken-images) with potentially orphaned images with the HTTPS move - folks are trickling these in. We also have had an ongoing project to fix tags that could use some love, or at least a certain temporary lack of restraint.

This is a much bigger project than the past [tag cleanup weekend](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8523/logistics-for-tag-cleanup-weekend-1), and yeah, we could/should have planned this earlier. I'll have words in the [appropriate place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) at some point of time

I'd like to propose having this from the 0000 UTC on the 16th of march 2017, running to 2359 UTC on the 23rd of march.

Things we need to do in the meanwhile is probably to update the tag cleanup posts.

If we do go ahead - I'll post a logistics question - ([like this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8523/logistics-for-tag-cleanup-weekend-1))on wednesday and we can move from there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The timing is terrible. We should do it but later - after the elections. And trickle in the orphaned images in the meantime

Comment: Brilliant!  Make it an initiation rite for the new moderator.  Task them with getting this done and see how they do in a trial by fire situation.  That way, everyone will know quickly whether we elected the right person.  Hopefully, there will be no lasting brain damage.

Comment: The whole point of this exercise is to do as little as possible as mods, and to do as much as possible with as little long lasting additional brain damage as possible

Comment: Exactly! and an effective mod will know that and recognize that delegation and motivation are the keys.  That was a "trick" suggestion to see if the candidates understand the role.  You pass.

Comment: Nice save. . :-)

Comment: Now that the election has concluded, are there plans for this to move ahead?

Comment: @BenN What's the link to the spreadsheet again? How are we doing already?

Comment: @DavidPostill The [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGmL-Ie0mNyCG5dpz7AAhn3sRaoNWkBJ0OvSoEacezs/edit?usp=sharing) in linked in [my meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12189/380318). We're doing pretty well, but there's still plenty more to go, and I believe there are also some tag burnings (the manufacturer ones) pending.

Answer (score 8):

Yay! Temporary total lack of editing restraints will help solve the problem.

Comment: The alternatives aren't mutually exclusive.  It wouldn't hurt to do this as part of the overall plan.

Comment: Originally, it was yay/nay. Then at least two people went "... dude, chill, terrible timing". And they were right.

Comment: I first read that "temporal" and was very confused.

Answer (score -1):

Nay! Front page floods are terrible! [Human Sacrifices, Cats and Dogs Living together! MASS HYSTERIA!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S4cldkdCjE)

Or we can deal with this slowly.

Comment: What!? You don't want to save the lives of millions of voters?