# Logistics for Cleanup Weekend 2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-weekends

We are having another cleanup weekend.

This time we will focus on:

- fixing the rest of the [broken images](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12189/lets-fix-all-the-broken-images) (most of this work has been completed)
- cleaning up some more tags

The cleanup will last for 48 hours and will be running from 2017-04-08 00:00:00 to 2017-04-10 00:00:00 UTC. To see that converted into your local time, you may visit http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/.

---

#### Fixing Broken Images

> One of the steps on Stack Exchange's road to HTTPS is the replacing of embedded http:// images with secure ones. This has been done automatically for a lot of images, but there are some that can't be automatically fixed. These were rewritten in the HTML (but not the Markdown source) to be text links instead of image embeds. It would be good to go through the affected posts and make images display correctly, or remove the link debris if they can't be restored.

To continually track our progress, we have a [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGmL-Ie0mNyCG5dpz7AAhn3sRaoNWkBJ0OvSoEacezs/edit?usp=sharing) created by [Ben N](https://meta.superuser.com/users/380318/ben-n). (Even though all the links have /q/, answers are included too.) The Status column is editable by anyone, so please note your work there as you go along.

Look for variations of "**Image no longer available**" and "**User screenshot no longer available**" in the Status column to find posts that still need to be fixed.

---

#### Tag Cleanup

Here is a [list of 15 tag cleanup requests](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-request+status-planned), one for each of the tags that are [status-planned](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-planned) (approved by the community) for cleanup.

What you need to do is listed in the individual tag cleanup requests.

---

#### Note

Our front page is likely to be filled with edits so using the [questions page](https://superuser.com/questions/) would be advised if you're *not* taking part in the cleanup. Apologies to any new users who've just come across this - it's not something we do very often.

Comment: Lovin' that new diamond by your name!

Comment: In the status column **User screenshot no longer available** refers to a missing image created by the OP that is usually integral to the post, and its absence may make the post unclear, or useless. Repairing those posts will be difficult anyone other than the OP. The **Image no longer available** is probably some image the OP found elsewhere, that _may_ not be as critical to the post. Product images, things pulled from old tutorials, etc., are likely candidates for the second option. Those posts may be easier to salvage without the OP's help.

Comment: It seems that the status "Image no longer available" is not always accurate. I have found some that were available that said they were not. Please recheck the availability before making major edits to remove the images completely.

Comment: __Image cleanup status update__: One post has an historical lock on it, that will require high-rep/mod attention. One has posted videos that are no longer available. One post _Links to a deleted Stack Overflow question_, but has no image left in it to explain the partitioning in question - maybe a mod to mod between sites can rescue that image and apply it to the Super User posting. Finally, 51 posts are listed under __User screenshot no longer available__, and their final status will have to be considered case-by-case as many don't make any sense without the image to explain the issue.

Comment: Do those reviewing Suggested Edits need to be as strict about requiring editors to fix *all/most* errors in a post when doing tag cleanup? Or should we be approving edits that only fix the tags and leave other things undone?

Comment: @Twisty Approving just tag edits is fine. There are many hundreds to do so we are not being too picky. If someone fixes other issues then that is a bounus.

Comment: Take two to reject anyway, and I _have_ been a bit lax in reviewing them. The ones that slap me in the face get fixed anyway. It's all for the good, so just keep plugging on. @Twisty What I've seen others do sometimes is to edit the edit. Don't know how they do that, but it fixes the problem they see, and gets it approved faster as well.

Comment: @Twisty That's ok, now you can fix the fix. _dd_ should be lower case because it is a *nix command, not an abbreviation.

Comment: @Twisty rather than bouncing comments here, why not join us in the SU chat room RootAccess? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Comment: Enlisting the support of <2K users creates massive edit review requirements.  Many higher-rep users have maxed out their limit of 20 reviews/day, leaving a ridiculous workload for you mods.  Is there a way to temporarily raise the review limit for regular users so we can assist?

Comment: @fixer1234 Not that I know of (I've done over 100 edit reviews today) :/

Comment: I'm still slowly removing old 'delete' tags.... I try not to flood the queue at @DavidPostill's request ;)